# How to use "this" in proxy macro in Clojure

Tags: clojure

I have such code:

```
(def prx (proxy [java.lang.Runnable] []
    (run 
      ([] (println "0000" 'this) 1))
    (toString ([] (str "------" 'this)))))

(.toString prx)
```

How to get "this" reference inside of proxy macro?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each method you implement gets `this` as their first arg.

See the docs:

> Method fns are closures and can capture the environment in
>   which proxy is called. Each method fn takes an additional implicit
>   first arg, which is bound to 'this.`

Also, check [this](https://puredanger.github.io/tech.puredanger.com/2011/08/12/subclassing-in-clojure/) article that goes into detail when to use `proxy` vs `reify` vs `gen-class`.